# Golang log function return arguments

Tags: logging, go

I would like to log a function's return values. The "smartest" thing I could come up with is wrapping my actual function body in a closure.

```
func foo(a int, b int) (int, error) {
    c, err := func (a int, b int) (int, error) {
        //...
        return c, err
    }(a, b)

    fmt.Printf("%v %v %v %v", a, b, c, err)

    return c, err
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with less boilerplate?

Comment: Is this just during debugging, or you want this to be a feature of your production code?

Comment: both, I'm currently developing in a kubernetes cluster and don't get a debugger running there and for production it's cool as you can get log based metrics really simple

Comment: and thanks for removing my greeting ✌️

Comment: lol.... generally greetings and closings are considered extraneous here. Not because we don't like being polite, but more because we just like to get to the point of the question.

Comment: true that, good point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but what about:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
)

func foo(a, b int) (c int, err error) {
    defer func() {log.Printf("%v %v %v %v", a, b, c, err)}()
    c = a + b
    return c, nil
}


func main() {
    foo(1, 3)
}
```

Comment: @Keeto, should you be returning `nil` instead of `err`? https://play.golang.org/p/_xcRpfC9u-

Comment: @srxf I just chose to return nil because my function body has no errors. You could return whatever you want. The defer function will pick on whatever the values of the return variables are and and log them or do any kind of processing on them

Comment: dope, that's a nice one.. def +1, I will wait 7 more days and if nobody comes up with sth smarter I'll accept your answer, thanks man! :)

Comment: Should it be just `defer log.Printf("%v %v %v %v", a, b, c, err)`?

Comment: @AlexanderTrakhimenok na, arguments passed to defer are evaluated instantly, so you would get c == 0 and err == nil.. with the func the arguments are evaluated once the func is executed

Answer (score 1):

There are two patterns I would consider:

1. As @Keeto suggests, you can use a 'defer' statement:

   ```
   func foo(a, b int) (c int, e error) {
       defer log.Printf("%v %v %v %v\n", a, b, c, err)
       // ... the function body
   }
   ```
2. A logging stub function:

   ```
   func foo(a, b int) (int, error) {
       c, err := realFoo(a, b)
       log.Printf("%v %v %v %v\n", a, b, c, err)
   }

   func realFoo(a, b int) (int, error) {
       // ... the function body
   }
   ```

A closure also works, as you mentioned in your question, but in my opinion, that's the least readable of the options.

Which you choose depends mainly on preference.  Performance should be roughly the same across the three options--but if performance is critical, do benchmarks to be sure, under your real application load.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: https://play.golang.org/p/VrPgH1VUwP

Basically, you just have to wrap them with some function that returns a function with the same signature but including the logging:

```
type fooFunc func(int, int) (int, error)

func fooLogger(f fooFunc) fooFunc {
    return func(a, b int) (int ,error){
        c, err := f(a, b)
        log.Printf("%s => a: %v, b: %v, return => c: %v, err: %v\n", fnName(f), a, b, c, err);
        return c, err
    }
}

func foo(a, b int) (int, error){
    c := a + b
    return c, nil
}


func main() {
    loggedFoo := fooLogger(foo)

    //prints something like this
    //2009/11/10 23:00:00 main.foo => a: 2, b: 2, return => c: 4, err: <nil>
    c, err := loggedFoo(2, 2)
    fmt.Println("from foo:", c, err)
}
```

Comment: cool idea, I don't like that you gotta write a "Logger" for every function signature though